# How can I translate this IDNA URL to Unicode?

Tags: go

I want to translate an IDNA ASCII URL to Unicode.

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/net/idna"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    input := "https://xn---36-mddtcafmzdgfgpbxs0h7c.xn--p1ai"
    idnaProfile := idna.New()
    output, err := idnaProfile.ToUnicode(input)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%s", output)
}
```

The output is: `https://xn---36-mddtcafmzdgfgpbxs0h7c.рф`

It seems the IDNA package only converts the TLD. Is there some option that can convert the full URL?

I need to get the same result as when I paste the ASCII URL into Chrome:
`https://природный-источник36.рф`

Comment: Thats not how idna works. Just convert the hostname alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to parse the URL first:

```golang
package main

import (
   "golang.org/x/net/idna"
   "net/url"
)

func main() {
   p, e := url.Parse("https://xn---36-mddtcafmzdgfgpbxs0h7c.xn--p1ai")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   s, e := idna.ToUnicode(p.Host)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   println(s == "природный-источник36.рф")
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/net/url#Parse

Answer (score -2):

An IDNA string consists of "labels" separated by dots ".". Each label may be encoded (if it starts with "xn--") or not (if it doesn't). Your string consists of two labels, `https://xn---36-mddtcafmzdgfgpbxs0h7c` and `xn--p1ai`. Only the second one is IDNA encoded.

Just process those parts of the URL which *are* IDNA encoded (i.e. the hostname). Anything else is just nonsensical and cannot work.

Comment: `Anything else is just nonsensical and cannot work.`
The URL part gets correctly translated to it's unicode form when pasting this to Chrome / Firefox browsers so it does work

Comment: @stkxchng The browser doesn't IIDNA-to-ASCII on the URL but on the individual components of the URL. You really should try to understand how these things work. Actually what browsers do is exactly what I and Steven stated in his accepted answer.